# onPostExecute is only sometimes called in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

My AsyncTask is executed in my MainActivity, but it doesn't call onPostExecute. The method doInBackground is finished until the return statement (checked with System.out)!

The Call:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (playIntent == null) {
        playIntent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);

        if (CheckPermissions()) {
            Prepare();
        }
    }
}

private void Prepare() {
    MusicStore musicStore = new MusicStore(getApplicationContext());

    sSongs = musicStore.getSongs();

    StoreParcel storeParcel = new StoreParcel(StoreParcel.StoreAction.READ_PLAYLISTS, this);

    musicStore.execute(storeParcel);

    if (sSongs.length < 1) {
        fabPlayPause.hide();

        snbInformation = Snackbar.make(recyclerView, getString(R.string.snb_Information) + "Music.", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        snbInformation.show();
    }
    else {
        fabPlayPause.show();
    }

    bindService(playIntent, musicServiceConn, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    startService(playIntent);
}
```

The AsyncTask:

```
public class MusicStore extends AsyncTask<StoreParcel, Void, StoreParcel> {
    private Context mContext;

    public MusicStore(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    //region AsyncTask

    @Override
    protected StoreParcel doInBackground(StoreParcel... params) {
        StoreParcel parcel = params[0];

        StoreParcel storeParcel = new StoreParcel(parcel.getAction(), parcel.getPlaylistInterface());

        switch (parcel.getAction()) {
            case WRITE_PLAYLISTS:
                WritePlaylists(parcel.getPlaylists());
                break;
            case READ_PLAYLISTS:
                storeParcel.setPlaylists(ReadPlaylists());
                break;
        }

        return storeParcel;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(StoreParcel storeParcel) {
        if (storeParcel.getAction() == StoreParcel.StoreAction.READ_PLAYLISTS) {
            storeParcel.getPlaylistInterface().SyncPlaylists(storeParcel.getPlaylists());
        }

        super.onPostExecute(storeParcel);
    }

    //region Methods

    private void WritePlaylists(Playlist[] playlists) {
        File dir = new File(mContext.getFilesDir() + Preferences.dirPlaylists);

        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
            f.delete();
        }

        if (playlists == null) return;

        String sFilename;
        File file;

        for (int i = 0; i < playlists.length; i++) {
            sFilename = playlists[i].getName();

            try {
                file = new File(dir, sFilename + ".json");
                file.createNewFile();

                Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file));

                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                gson.toJson(playlists[i], writer);

                    writer.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private Playlist[] ReadPlaylists() {
        Playlist[] playlists;

        File dir = new File(mContext.getFilesDir() + Preferences.dirPlaylists);

        File[] files = dir.listFiles();

        if (files == null) return null;

        playlists = new Playlist[files.length];

        Reader reader = null;

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(files[i]));

                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                playlists[i] = gson.fromJson(reader, Playlist.class);
            }

            if (reader != null) reader.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        return playlists;
    }

    //endregion

    //endregion
}
```

The StoreParcel is a class created by me! It only countains an Interface, and an Enum-Value!

Comment: Can you post the complete `AsyncTask`, I mean, with `class`?

Comment: So I've added the full MusicStore class!

Comment: I can guarantee you `onPostExecute` is always called, but `storeParcel.getAction()` is sometimes not equal to `READ_PLAYLISTS`

Comment: and why is the system.out in onPostExecute not called?
my app doesn't load because of this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should run the task in onResume so you are the ui exists.  You can do UI stuff in onStart and onPostExecute has to run on UI thread.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
  super.onStart();

  if (playIntent == null) {
    playIntent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
  }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (CheckPermissions()) {
        Prepare();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be that the UI freezed because I wait for the onPostExecute in MainActivity with `while (!bPlaylistsLoaded) { }` ??

Comment: Maybe. No need for that since AsyncTask handles UI and worker thread stuff for you.

Comment: Awesome! Glad you figured it out.